# wrirting rollback after handling exception

Tags: plsql

I have a scenario in which, i am writing the exception like this

```
     when others then
         rollback;
         p_status     := 'ERROR'; -- MODIFIED
         p_status_dtl := sqlcode||' - '||substr(sqlerrm,1,100);
end;
```

if i write like this

```
exception
     when others then
                      p_status     := 'ERROR'; -- MODIFIED
                      p_status_dtl := sqlcode||' - '||substr(sqlerrm,1,100);
             rollback;
end;
```

does it make a difference if yes what is the difference.

Answer (score 3):

The examples are identical if the variable assignments don't throw (i.e. both `p_status` and `p_status_dtl` are correct data type with enough storage).

If the variable assignment throws then in the second example `rollback` is not executed.

In the example below only `checkpoint 1` will be printed:

```
declare
  v_foo varchar2(2) := 'AB';
  v_bar number;
begin
  -- raises ORA-01476: divisor is equal to zero
  v_bar := 1/0;
exception
  when others then
    dbms_output.put_line('checkpoint 1');
    -- raises ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small
    v_foo := 'TOO LONG';
    dbms_output.put_line('checkpoint 2');
end;
/
```